# Contar cuantas veces se repite una palabra en un texto

Tags: python

Buen día para todos.

Quiero leer un archivo y contar las veces que se repite x palabra, ya tengo un código que realice, pero me esta seleccionando palabras muy poco claras.

```
#FRECUENCIA DE PALABRAS
print('Número de palabras en el archivo de texto :', total_p)

quitar = ",;:.\n!\"'"
for caracter in quitar:
    texto = texto.replace(caracter,"")
    
texto = texto.lower()
palabras = texto.split(" ")

diccionario_frecuencias = {}
for palabra in palabras:
    if palabra in diccionario_frecuencias:
        diccionario_frecuencias[palabra] += 1
    else:
        diccionario_frecuencias[palabra] = 1

for palabra in diccionario_frecuencias:
    frecuencia = diccionario_frecuencias[palabra]
    print(f"La palabra '{palabra}' tiene una frecuencia de {frecuencia}")
```

salida:

````
La palabra 'ylugares' tiene una frecuencia de 1
La palabra 'entoncesdebía' tiene una frecuencia de 1
La palabra 'valer' tiene una frecuencia de 1
La palabra 'últimoshabitantes' tiene una frecuencia de 1
La palabra 'buenhumor' tiene una frecuencia de 1 ```

como se puede ver en la salida, me esta uniendo palabra y por esa razón algunas que se pueden contar como repetidas se cuentan separadas, me gustaría saber si hay una mejor manera de hacerlo y que cuente las palabras separadas bien.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que lees todo el texto de una sola vez, y luego reemplazas los "\n" por nada. En consecuencia, la última palabra de la línea y la primera palabra de la siguiente línea quedan unidas.

Es mejor una solución con expresiones regulares:

```
import re

contador = {}
patron = re.compile(r"(\w+)")
with open("quijote.txt", "r") as texto:
    for linea in texto.readlines():
        m = patron.findall(linea)
        for palabra in m:
            palabra = palabra.lower()
            if palabra in contador:
                contador[palabra] += 1
            else:
                contador[palabra] = 1
print(contador)
```

Usamos la expresión regular `\w+`, que reconoce palabras compuestas de letras, digitos y "_". Al poner esta expresión entre parentesis, creamos un *grupo de captura*, es decir, señalamos que el texto reconocido debe guardarse.

`findall()` busca todas las ocurrencias de la expresión regular y las retorna como una lista. De ahi sólo queda actualizar los contadores.

Comment: Lo que hiciste lo entendí, pero creo que al momento de mostrarlo con el for no me esta arrojando de la manera adecuada o creo que lo estoy haciendo mal. Tu muestras directamente el dic, yo trato con el for y no da los mismo resultado que mostrando con el ```print(contador)```

Comment: Cual seria la manera correcta de mostrarlo con palabra valor, porque trato y solo me aparece que se ha repetido 1, 2 si mucho.

Comment: Por ejemplo el ```print(contador)``` aroja esto ```{'gabriel': 184, 'garcía': 173, 'márquez': 242, 'cien': 179, 'años': 357, 'de': 8858, 'soledad': 217, 'para': 1021, 'jomi': 1, 'ascot': 1, 'y': 4149, 'al': 853, 'pelotón': 23, 'fusilamiento': 24, 'el': 4057, 'coronel': 312, 'aureliano': 795, 'buendía': 411, 'había': 892,  'en': 3886, 'que': 4683,``` pero cuando recorro con un for contador, no me muestra todos eso valores o no aparece la palabra. Es muy raro

Comment: @JohnJames. Tu parte de mostrar los resultados está bien, por lo que no la inclui en mi respuesta. Es el mismo código, reemplazando `contador` con `diccionario_frecuencias`.

Comment: SI, eso me fije pero al momento de mostrarlo como lo tenia, pero, como que no me muestra todos los resultados. Es muy raro!!